# How do I tell cmake to do these two steps to use winpcap?

Tags: c, windows, cmake, winpcap

Quoted from [here](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_40_2/html/group__wpcapsamps.html):

- If your program uses Win32 specific functions of WinPcap, remember to include WPCAP  among the preprocessor definitions.
- If your program uses the remote capture capabilities of WinPcap, add HAVE_REMOTE among the preprocessor definitions. Do not include remote-ext.h directly in your source files.

Has anyone managed to use winpcap with cmake?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
add_definitions(-DWPCAP -DHAVE_REMOTE)

find_path(WINPCAP_INCLUDE_DIR pcap.h
         ${WINPCAP_HINT_INCLUDE_DIR})

find_library(WINPCAP_LIBRARY NAMES "wpcap"
                             PATHS ${WINPCAP_HINT_LIB_DIR})

...

include_directories(${WINPCAP_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_library(my_lib ${WINPCAP_LIBRARY})
```